# Hide image when hovering over a parent element

Tags: html, css

I am currently trying to give an image an `opacity: 0` whenever I hover over the div in which it is located. Currently, the opacity is only applied to the image when I hover over the actual image, not when I hover over the parent div. My current code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="Test" style="background-color:#D12121;padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:5px;">
    <div class="fadeSponsorsSmall">
        <img src="img/icon/small/white/sponsors.png">
        <p style="color:white;"><b>Gastenboek</b></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.fadeSponsorsSmall {
    background-image: url('../img/icon/small/black/sponsors.png');
    background-size: 50px 50px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 22px 0px;
}
.fadeSponsorsSmall img:hover {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

I need to make the image have an opacity of 0 whenever I hover over either the image or anything with a class of `.test`.

Comment: use .fadeSponsorsSmall:hover img { opacity: 0; }

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need something simple like this:

## [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Luxelin/Bj8uQ/1/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="test">Hover over me!
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/300">
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.test:hover img {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Since the `<img>` is inside of the `<div>` you just need to apply the `:hover` pseudo class to the div and apply the style to the image, hence `.test:hover img { ... }`.

Comment: @TienusMcVinger If I successfully answered your question, you should consider accepting it. Accepting an answer is a vital part of stack overflow Q+A, as it allows for closure and tells other SO users not to waste time on a given question, as it has already been answered.

Comment: Ah, right. I remember trying to do so at first, but I had to wait a bit before accepting that - afterwards I completely forgot about it! Shall accept your answer now.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
.Test:hover .fadeSponsorsSmall{
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Then when you hover over the div with the class of Test, the opacity of the div with the class of fadeSponsorsSmall will be 0.

You could also remove div with the class of fadeSponsorsSmall, give the photo an id and target that instead.

Answer (score 0):

Just change your CSS with this one

```
.fadeSponsorsSmall:hover img
{
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
.Test:hover {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add this to your CSS

```
.Test:hover
{
    opacity: 0;
}
```